# Displaying name of directory or directories which do not have a specified file

Tags: c#, .net, file, path

I have a main folder in which there are a set of sub directories . each of these sub directories are expected to have an file named app.config .. I have written a method which will scan the directory and obtain the path of all folders which have this file but I want to write in the console the name of the sub directories which do not have this file

is it possible to obtain this behavior with this implementation ?

my code is as below

```
private void ValidateFiles(string path)
{
    var filesindirectory = new List<string>(Directory
      .GetFiles(path, "app.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

    foreach (var file in filesindirectory)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *Linq*: we want *all* directories such that they don't have `app.config` file:

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 List<string> dirs = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(dir => !File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, "app.config")))
    .ToList(); // If we want to have a list of such directories
```

In case you want just to write the directories:

```
 var dirs = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(dir => !File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, "app.config")));

 foreach (string directory in dirs)
   Console.WriteLine(directory);
```

**Edit:** Let's come to terms. We have root directory (`path`) with subdirectories which can have `app.config` file:

```
    C: 
      \Root # == path
        \SubDir1
          app.config
        \SubDir2
          app.config
          \SubSubDir2_1
            app.config
          \SubSubDir2_2
        \SubDir3
          readme.txt
          \SubSubDir3_1
            settings.xml 
        \SubDir4
          \SubSubDir4_1
            app.config
```

The code above returns all the subdirectories (including nested ones) which doesn't have `app.config`:

```
     C:\Root\SubDir2\SubSubDir2_1
     C:\Root\SubDir3
     C:\Root\SubDir3\SubSubDir3_1
     C:\Root\SubDir4
```

If you want, say, *top-level* subdirs (`SubDir1..SubDir4`) which don't have `app.config` within them or within their own subdirectories:

```
 var dirs = Directory
   .EnumerateDirectories(path)
   .Where(dir => !Directory
      .EnumerateFiles(dir, "app.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
      .Any());
```

and we'll have

```
     C:\Root\SubDir3
```

only since neither `SubDir3` nor its subdirs (`SubSubDir3_1`) contain `app.config`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I think you might have mis understood a little . Say my main Directory is A and I have the sub directories P,Q,R,S . out of which S is missing this config file
I simply want to print "S" in the console
The tricky part here is that this config file can be any where inside that folder

Comment: Yes I did  , it did not quite work the way I expected